# fastapi cannot browser API documentation

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

My project directory structure is like this:

```bash
.
├── .env
│   ├── Include
│   ├── Lib
│   ├── Scripts
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── .vscode
│   └── launch.json
└── src
    ├── __pycache__
    └── main.py
```

I write some code in the main.py file:

```py
import fastapi
from fastapi import FastAPI

app=FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def health():
    return "ok"

@app.get("/version")
def version():
    return fastapi.__version__
```

Then launch the project: `uvicorn main:app --port 9090 --root-path src --reload`
I can request APIs successed, but when I try to browser the swagger documents, I will get a **fetch error**:
[image]

```bash
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50659 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50659 - "GET /src/openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

Should I do some configuration to resolve this problem? I use `python v3.10.5` and `fastapi v0.85.0`, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root-path` parameter is used in situations where you use a reverse proxy. If your reverse proxy adds a path to your URL, your code can still ignore that path.

From the docs:

> Having a proxy with a stripped path prefix, in this case, means that
> you could declare a path at /app in your code, but then, you add a
> layer on top (the proxy) that would put your FastAPI application under
> a path like /api/v1.
>
> In this case, the original path /app would actually be served at
> /api/v1/app.
>
> Even though all your code is written assuming there's just /app.

It is **not** used to point to a folder in your project structure. So, remove the root-path param in your uvicorn command and you should be good to go.